# Stored procedure and parameters in ASPX website

Tags: procedure

I have a stored procedure that takes 'pnum' as parameter and i want this parameter to be included in the **url** to an aspx website and then display the fetched data in a datagrid. The problem I'm having is that I dont know what to chose in the parameter source.

Answer (score -1):

You can pass information between pages in various ways, some of which depend on how the redirection occurs. The following options are available even if the source page is in a different ASP.NET Web application from the target page, or if the source page is not an ASP.NET Web Forms page:

1. Use a query string.
2. Get HTTP POST information from the source page.

As you want the parameter to be a part of the URL, a QueryString is the best option

**Using a Query String**

When you use a **hyperlink** or **Response.Redirect** to navigate from one page to another, you can add information in a query string at the end of the URL.

*Note : Never pass sensitive data using a query string, because the information is visible to users and can easily be modified, thus representing a potential security risk.*

To use a query string to pass information
In the source Web Forms page when you specify the URL of the target page, include the information that you want to pass in the form of key-value pairs at the end of the URL.

The first pair is preceded by a question mark (?) and subsequent pairs are preceded by ampersands(&), as shown in the following example:

```
http://contoso.com/products.aspx?field1=value1

http://contoso.com/products.aspx?field1=value1&field2=value2
```

In the target page, access query string values by using the QueryString property of the HttpRequest object, as shown in the below :

```
String s = Request.QueryString["field1"];
```

More information about [QueryString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring(v=vs.140).aspx)